# How to create a multivalued attribute on SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

There is a way to create a multivalued attribute in SQL command?

[image]

There is a code:

```
CREATE TABLE fornecedor (
    Id INTEGER,
    Nome VARCHAR(30),
    Morada   ????????????????
    Email VARCHAR(20)
)
```

Comment: Hint: Search for *database normalization*. Data in column should be atomic. Probably the best way is to define tables: attribute and junction table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two ways:

1. have the four attributes in the table directly:

   - fornecedor: id, nome, rua, n_porta, cod_postal, localidade, email, telefone.
2. have an address table:

   - endereço: id, rua, n_porta, cod_postal, localidade.
   - fornecedor: id, nome, id_endereço, email, telefone.

You would decide for the latter, if you have multiple fornecedores using the same address. Otherwise simply use the first solution and have the address fields in the fornecedor table.

Comment: I should add: Some DBMS even really provide exactly what you thought of: have an object in a table. Oracle does. MySQL does not. But in spite of having used Oracle for many, many years, objects in a table never appealed to me and I never used them.

Answer (score 1):

You should have 4 attributes `Morada_Rua` , `Morada_NPorta`, ... instead. Sql has no standard for address data type comparable to `date` data type for which a number of fuctions are defined to get `Year`, `Month` and other parts of date.

Answer (score 0):

Another option would be to use the JSON datatype for attribute (column) `Morada`, which allows to store any kind of data in a structured way. MySQL supports this type since 5.7.